# PHP recursive creation of db queries after multidimensional form submission: fk field sometimes "omitted", but why and how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

NOTE: SOLUTION FOUND

I am trying to build a (my first!) PHP/JQuery/MySQL web app able to work with multidimensional data. In current state, almost everything works fine but one strange bug occurs when submitting data (see title) and I haven't found any explanation. Can anyone open my eyes?

When working my test form with 5 dimensional data (table names - one, two, three, four, five - all joined in chain):

- if I submit completely new entry with all dimensions then all 5 INSERT INTO queries are generated correctly
- but if I add to the existing entry (under 2nd dim) new 3rd dimension with corresponding child data (4th and 5th) - that means tables three, four and five - then foreign key field in table five (four_id) is omitted from the insertion query
- all the rest options (two, three, four and five or new four and five) have no issues

There are 3 functions in php that are doing the work (first for main table, second for next 2 dimensions and third (recursive) for next n dimensions). As tables four and five in this example are "belonging" to the recursive one I am quite sure that the issue and key for solution should be there.

Each function is using both form data and existing data that is already submitted. Pk value of parent row is passed to the child in two possible ways:

1. After each INSERT INTO query a MySQL variable for new pk value is created: SET @last_id_tablename = LAST_INSERT_ID() to be used in child query when needed. If data submitted to parent and child (say four and five) is new for both tables then child table's query should be (and normally is)

   - INSERT INTO five (four_id, title) VALUES (@last_id_four, 'Some text')
2. If parent data is already existing and we add new related child row then the existing parent pk value (say 1) is passed to the child and query is

   - INSERT INTO five (four_id, title) VALUES (1, 'Some text')

So the issue is that when I have an entry with first 2 dimensions and I add 3 dimensions under existing 2nd (IOW I have parent row in one with its child row in two and under this I add new data starting from table three the generated queries are:

- INSERT INTO three (two_id, title) values (1, 'Some text');
- INSERT INTO four (three_id, title) values (@last_id_three, 'Some text')
- INSERT INTO five (title) values ('Some text')

As you see, four_id and @last_id_four are missing in third line.

All other combinations including fully new data submmission for all dimensions are generating a correct query for five. Fully new data submission query list looks like this one (first table's last id is returned before the rest continues, passed to the next function and therefore it's in use already as a real number, let's say 10)

```
INSERT INTO one (title) values ('Some text');

INSERT INTO two (one_id, title) values (10, 'Some text');
SET @last_id_two = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO three (two_id, title) values (@last_id_two, 'Some text');
SET @last_id_three = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO four (three_id, title) values (@last_id_three, 'Some text')
SET @last_id_four = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO five (four_id, title) values (@last_id_four, 'Some text')
```

The only one explanation I thought about was that it's somehow related to the variable names in the recursive function and therefore I renamed all of vars but it didn't resolve the issue.

Below I show the full code of this recursive function

```
/* 
    Recursive function for inserting or editing nested data (since 4th until nth level)

    $subTable - current table where we insert new or edit existing data
    $subData - current table's data in form view
    $existingSubJoin - current table data that is already in database (submitted earlier)
    $existing... - corresponding variables for existing data 
    $parentTable - current table's parent table (where current tables FK is pointing)
    $existingParentJoin -  parent table data that already exists 
    $parentPkField, $parentPkValue - the names are self-explanatory
    $parentPkValue can be a real number from existing row or @last_id_$parentTable
    @last_id_$subTable - a MySQL variable that passes the last_insert_id() value from newly submitted parent row to the child row's FK 
    $subSingle - a new array of db field values for one row 
    $subSet - array for UPDATE statements (SET field = 'value', field2 = 'value2' etc)
    $subFields - array of fields for INSERT INTO 
    $nextLastId = pk value or @last_id_$subTable to be passed as a last argument for next recursion


*/
public function buildQueryListChild($subTable, $subData, $existingSubJoin, $parentTable, $existingParentJoin, $parentPkField, $parentPkValue)
{

    if (isset($subData))
    {
        foreach($subData as $sKey => $subRow)
        {
            $subSingle = array();

            if (!isset($existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey]))
            {
                $existingSubRow = $existingSubJoin['rows'][0];
            }
            else
            {
                $existingSubRow = $existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey];
            }

            $subSet = array();

            $subParentId = $parentTable . '_' . $parentPkField;

            foreach ($subRow as $subField => $subValue)
            {
                if (isset($existingSubJoin['properties']['fields']))
                {
                    foreach ($existingSubJoin['properties']['fields'] as $existingSubField)
                    {
                        if ($existingSubField['name'] == $subField)
                        {

                            if ($existingSubField['key'] == 'PRI')
                            {
                                $subRowPkField = $existingSubField['name'];
                                $subRowPkAlias = $existingSubField['alias'];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $subRowField = $existingSubField['name'];
                                $subRowAlias = $existingSubField['alias'];
                                $subRowType = $existingSubField['type'];
                            }


                            $sNumTypes = array('int', 'float', 'decimal', 'numeric', 'double', 'bit');

                            foreach ($sNumTypes as $sType)
                            {
                                $sNumber = strpos($existingSubField['type'], $sType) === true ? true : null;
                            }

                            $sString = $sNumber ? false : true;

                        }
                    }
                }

                if (empty($subRow[$subRowPkField]))
                {
                    $newSub = true;
                    $updateSub = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $updateSub = true;
                    $newSub = false;
                }

                if (!is_array($subValue))
                {

                    if ($subField != $subRowPkField && strpos($subRowType, 'timestamp') === false)
                    {

                        if ($subField == $subParentId)
                        {
                            $subSingle[$subParentId] = $parentPkValue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!empty($subValue)) $subSingle[$subField] = $subValue;
                        }

                        if ($updateSub && $subField == $subRowField && $subSingle[$subField] != $existingSubRow['data'][$subRowAlias])
                        {
                            $uSubField = $subField;
                            $uSubValue = $subValue;
                            if (!$sNumber)
                            {
                                $uSubValue = "'$subValue'";
                            }

                            $subSet[$uSubField] = "$uSubField = $uSubValue";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!empty($subSet))
            {
                $subSets = implode(', ', $subSet);
                $subRowPkValue = $subRow[$subRowPkField];
                $current = "UPDATE $subTable SET $subSets WHERE $subRowPkField = $subRowPkValue;\n";
                $sql .= $current;
            }

            if ($newSub)
            {
                $subRowPkValue = $subRow[$subRowPkField];

                if (!empty($subSingle))
                {
                    $subFields = implode(', ', array_keys($subSingle));
                    $subValues = "'" . implode("', '", array_values($subSingle)) . "'";
                    $subValues = str_replace("'$parentPkValue'", "$parentPkValue", $subValues);
                    $current = "INSERT INTO $subTable ($subFields) VALUES ($subValues);\n";
                    $sql .= $current;
                    $sql .= "SET @last_id_$subTable = LAST_INSERT_ID();\n";
                }
            }

            foreach ($subRow as $sTable => $sData)
            {
                if (is_array($sData)) 
                {
                    if (isset($existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey]) && $sKey > 0)
                    {
                        $nextLastId = $sKey;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $nextLastId = "@last_id_$subTable";
                    }
                    $existingSData = $existingSubRow['joins']->$sTable;
                    $sql .= $this->buildQueryListChild($sTable, $sData, $existingSData, $subTable, $existingSubJoin, $subRowPkField, $nextLastId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $sql;
}
```

You see there a line

```
$current = "INSERT INTO $subTable ($subFields) VALUES ($subValues);\n";
```

where both $subFields and $subValues are imploded from corresponding submission array (array_keys and array_values) that is created in

```
                    if ($subField == $subParentId)
                    {
                        $subSingle[$subParentId] = $parentPkValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!empty($subValue)) $subSingle[$subField] = $subValue;
                    }
```

And as said, ($subFields) should always contain parenttable_id and ($subValues) its existing value or @last_id_parenttable

Sorry for this amount of information and thanks in advance for help!

SOLUTION FOUND - see ANSWER

There were also other issues that occurred in my code but, like changes I made in parent function, this is outside of this issue's scope. I hope all my explanations are clear :)

Comment: **WARNING**: This is an enormous amount of code to review, but the one thing that stands out, right away, is the extraordinary lack of proper SQL escaping. You **must** properly escape values. Ideally you use *prepared statements with placeholder values*.

Comment: From a code design principle, this needs to be split up into smaller, more focused functions. Instead of trying to do everything in one mega-sized function, try and think in terms of smaller operations that do something specific like transform from format A to format B or use format B to construct a statement. These can be more easily tested, especially with *unit testing* to verify the parts work according to your intentions.

Comment: Well, just ask others for help and you find a solution by yourself, LOL!

Comment: But your comments I believe are useful as well and yes, @tadman , I have such intention to split this and some others to smaller pieces. But current issue was (partially) caused by the fact that in particular cases the parent pk field name wasn't passed to child. And I'll try to find the place where to  edit the original post and add the solution.

Comment: Sometimes in the process of describing the problem you find the solution. See also: "cardboard programmer" or ["rubber-duck debugging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). If you found a workable solution you may want to add that as a self-answer to explain to others who might be in the same situation.

Comment: yes, "rubber-duck" is a well-known adviser :)

Answer (score 0):

The (main?) cause was that the parent pk field name was not always passed to child. I discovered this when I got idea that the way how the fk value was set was not the best one and that this should be done at very beginning, before creating a new array. So the first thing I did was that I moved it right before iterating the fields

```
$subParentId = $parentTable . '_' . $parentPkField;

$subRow[$subParentId] = $parentPkValue;

foreach ($subRow as $subField => $subValue)
{ ... }
```

But it wasn't enough. Yes, I got the needed value but without $parentPkField so I got a nonexisting field name (parenttablename_). Therefore it was clear what I should really look for.

And I got it. Some time ago I built among others a "blank row" feature to be used in some cases when there is no real db row. In this case I just forgot to use it where needed :D

Therefore I had to make some corrections also to the parent function and pass an additional $blank array from there to the child. And of course corresponding changes to the current function. This way the existence of $parentPkField was ensured.

The diffs in this function are here (old commented, new below or otherwise explained)

```
/* 
public function buildQueryListChild($subTable, $subData, $existingSubJoin, $parentTable, $existingParentJoin, $parentPkField, $parentPkValue)
*/
public function buildQueryListChild($subTable, $subData, $existingSubJoin, $blank, $parentTable, $existingParentJoin, $parentPkField, $parentPkValue)
{
    .....

    if (!isset($existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey]))
    {
        // $existingSubRow = $existingSubJoin['rows'][0];
        $existingSubRow = $blank['rows'][0];
    }

    ......

    // Added
    $subRow[$subParentId] = $parentPkValue;
    ......

    foreach ($subRow as $subField => $subValue)
    {
        // Added
        if (!$existingSubJoin) $existingSubJoin = $blank;

        ......
            if ($subField != $subRowPkField && strpos($subRowType, 'timestamp') === false)
            {

                /* 
                if ($subField == $subParentId)
                {
                    $subSingle[$subParentId] = $parentPkValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!empty($subValue)) $subSingle[$subField] = $subValue;
                } 
                */

                if (!empty($subValue)) $subSingle[$subField] = $subValue;
        .......

    if ($newSub)
    {
        // Removed as unneeded
        //$subRowPkValue = $subRow[$subRowPkField];

        if (!empty($subSingle))
        {
            ........

    // if / else moved here, see below foreach

    if (isset($existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey]) && $sKey > 0)
    {
        $nextLastId = $sKey;
    }
    else
    {
        $nextLastId = "@last_id_$subTable";
    }

    foreach ($subRow as $sTable => $sData)
    {
        if (is_array($sData)) 
        {
            /* 
            if (isset($existingSubJoin['rows'][$sKey]) && $sKey > 0)
            {
                $nextLastId = $sKey;
            }
            else
            {
                $nextLastId = "@last_id_$subTable";
            } 
            */
            // The commented lines above: moved them before foreach but actually not sure if it had any impact

            //Added 
            $nextBlank = $blank['rows'][0]['joins']->$sTable;

            /* 
            $sql .= $this->buildQueryListChild($sTable, $sData, $existingSData, $subTable, $existingSubJoin, $subRowPkField, $nextLastId);
            */

            $sql .= $this->buildQueryListChild($sTable, $sData, $existingNextData, $nextBlank, $subTable, $existingSubJoin, $subRowPkField, $nextLastId);
```